# HTML CSS two column layout with subcolumns in left column

Tags: css, layout, html

I want to get the following layout

```
 aaaaaaaaa  |  bbbb
 aaaaaaaaa  |  bbbb
  cc | dd   |  bbbb
  cc | dd   |  bbbb
  cc | dd   |  bbbb
```

the area for the "b"'s should have a fixed width.
the area for the "a"'s should take the rest of the available space.
"c"'s and "d"'s get 50% of the width of a each.

I can do this with tables without any problem.

I guess one of you guys can guide me on how to do this with DIVs and CSS.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-2-column-right-menu-pixels.htm 
has what looks like the basis for a Div based solution.

but I also need to be convinced that this is the right thing to do.
because it does come with a price... 
both in code size and in development time....

I want this to work on IE 7 and recent versions of chrome and FF.

(I just read this discussion: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/CSS/Q_21694743.html which I started about 5 years ago, I still dont like CSS Floating divs...)

also - does anybody know how supported is this: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/ ?

current code but its not stable in any way, i keep playing with it.. but nothing seems to do what I need:

```
<div id="_home_container_div" style="background-color:red;">
    <div style="float:right;background-color:violet;width:155px;margin-top:55px;margin-right:55px;marginleft:55px;">
        <div class="slideshow" style="width:100%;padding:0px auth;background-color:green;">
                       some images go here
        </div>
    <div id='caption' style="width:100%;padding:0px auth;font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; ">
        initial caption for first image
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;margin-top:55px;background-color:blue;">
        <div class="h1text" style="float:left;">
            <h1 class="_home_main_caption">${Home.main__header}</h1>
            <p class="h1text">${Home.main1__para}</p>
            <p class="h1text">${Home.main2__para}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="h2text" style="float:left;clear:left;">
            <h2>${Home.subA__header}</h2>
            <p>${Home.subA1__para}</p>
            <p>${Home.subA2__para}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="h2text" style="float:left;clear:left;">
            <h2>${Home.subB__header}</h2>
            <p>${Home.subB1__para}</p>
            <p>${Home.subB2__para}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: The code you have at the minute would be useful.

Comment: found an answer for my last (also -...) Q here: http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnunr/) helps you out.

Code:

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="left">
        aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa
        <div id="subLeft">
            cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
        </div>
        <div id="subRight">
            dd dd dd dd dd dd dd
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#cont
{
    width: 300px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}
#left
{
    float: left;
    width: 64%;
    background: lightblue;
}
#right
{
    width: 36%;
    background: red;
    float: right;
}

#subLeft
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: cyan;
}
#subRight
{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: It seems like i was missing a basic width for somthing - I started providing widths and now things look much better. thanks.

Comment: @epeleg Yea, specifying widths for each container/column is important for these kinds of layouts. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each area in DIVs.

Give area B a CSS *right* attribute, specifying its fixed width. Also set *position:absolute*. This will effectively move all the rest to the left by that amount.

Give area A a CSS *width* of 100%, and areas C and D get a CSS *width* of 50% each. You can enclose areas C and D in a table with one row and two columns - it may not be the cleanest solution but it's probably the easiest way to get them side by side. Areas C and D are nested within the DIV of area A.

Comment: Also, for columns, favour HTML lists over table columns.

Comment: can you explay why is position:absolue needed here?

Comment: also - wont the content from the left side crawl under the right side if its longer ?

Comment: position:absolute sets different parts of the layout to be independent of one another, otherwise they are rendered relatively (one after the other). By setting *right*, you sort of set a margin (it's actually a positioning, but think of it as a margin) for the rest of the page. That way, it will wrap before it overlaps the right side.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col col-content">
        <div class="section-wrapper">
            <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            <div class="section">
                <p>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <p>ddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sidebar">
        <p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:#DFD;
}

.col-content .section {
    width:49%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FDD;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.col-sidebar {
    width:300px;   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkLqg/)

Comment: just a quick and dirty based off the example provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HW2xR/) of the problem you are trying to solve.

The only real tricky bit is letting `.a` expand to the left-over width. The `.wrapper` has a padding width of the exact same width as the right column to accommodate it. In my example I've added a fixed-width to b (like you mentioned) of 200px. That column (`.b`) uses a negative margin-right (200px) to put it in the correct place. All of the browsers you mentioned should render this solution in exactly the same manner.

---

**Markup**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="d"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Styles**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
.a {
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
.b {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -200px;
  background: green;
}
.c {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}
.d {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  background: gold;
}
```